# dropdownlist for following

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html.dropdownlistfor

```
    var dropdown = (from role in db.aspnet_Users
                       where role.aspnet_Roles.Any(a => a.RoleName == "supervisor")
                       select new
                       {
                           text = role.UserName,
                           value = role.UserId
                       }).ToList();
```

code to generate dropdown list having dropdown.text as DropdownList item/text
 and dropdown.value as DropdownList value
**This code Present in my view.cshtml**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using razor:

```
    @Html.DropDownList("name",
         new SelectList( dropdown ,
                "value",
                "text" ) )
```

where dropdown is your variable

Also considering moving your code to the controller and passing the variable through viewbag (ie: ViewBag.dropdownitems = dropdown)